# How to get success or error data without folding the response while using fpdart in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, functional-programming

I'm using [fpdart](https://pub.dev/packages/fpdart) for catching errors in my flutter app. I wanted to get error message or success message directly without folding the whole response. There is getRight() and getLeft() method on res object but it returns `Option<Success Data Type>` and `Option<Error Data Type>` respectively. How could i extract the data directly without folding?

```
Future<Either<String, int>> getData() async {
  try {
    int data = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => 15);
    return right(data);
   } catch (err) {
    return left(err.toString());
  }
 }
```

Comment: Your best bet will be a pattern match, which will still end up looking a lot like a fold.  You cannot ask for the Right of a Left, or the Left of a Right.  That's why you get options back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mostly create extension for this.

```dart
extension EitherExt on Either {
  ///! use only after checking the type
  get asLeft => (this as Left).value;
  get asRight => (this as Right).value;
}
```

And you can use like

```dart
final result = await getData(); 
///prefer checking `result.isRight()` on toplevel
final myInt = result.asRight;
```

Comment: You might as well have done pattern matching by then.  Your asLeft will blow up if it's a Right, and vice-versa.  You've turned calculations into exceptions!

Comment: That's true, we can throw exception instead